# How to find matching date index in multiple dataframes FASTER without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find matching index for each date inside a multiple dataframes. if a date is found inside a dataframe, then move to next matching date. I am using a loop and it is very slow when dataframe is big. I am looking for a way to make it faster. Thanks for your help.

Here is the way I am doing. It will be slow when dataframe is big and number of time to find is big. Here is just a simple example.

I think using loop is not a good idea. However I have to check if a data is inside a dataframe or not. that is why I have to loop over each date. Thanks for your help.

```
df_tomatch_1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[10,20,30,40]})
df_tomatch_1.index=['2023-01-01 10:00','2023-01-01 11:00','2023-01-01 12:00','2023-01-01 13:00']
df_tomatch_1

    a   b
2023-01-01 10:00    1   10
2023-01-01 11:00    2   20
2023-01-01 12:00    3   30
2023-01-01 13:00    4   40

df_tomatch_2=pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2,3,4],'d':[10,20,30,40]})
df_tomatch_2.index=['2023-01-02 10:00','2023-01-02 11:00','2023-01-02 12:00','2023-01-02 13:00']
df_tomatch_2

    c   d
2023-01-02 10:00    1   10
2023-01-02 11:00    2   20
2023-01-02 12:00    3   30
2023-01-02 13:00    4   4

time_tomatch=['2023-01-01 10:30','2023-01-01 12:30','2023-01-02 11:30']

def find_matched_date_index(df_tomatch_list,time_tomatch):
    indx_time=[]
    for date_str in time_tomatch:
        print(date_str)
        thisdate=pd.to_datetime(date_str)
        # print('this date is',date_str
        for ix_file,df in enumerate(df_tomatch_list):
            df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
            if thisdate>=df.index[0]-timedelta(days=0.01) and thisdate<=df.index[-1]+timedelta(days=0.01):
                indx_found=df.index.get_indexer([thisdate],method='nearest')[0]
                indx_time.append([ix_file,indx_found])
                break   # exit for loop of dataframe
    return indx_time

indx_time=find_matched_date_index([df_tomatch_1,df_tomatch_2],time_tomatch)
print(indx_time)

2023-01-01 10:30
2023-01-01 12:30
2023-01-02 11:30
[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of what you are trying to find. Locate only the dates regardless of the hours?

Comment: sorry I just edit it a litte bit. I am trying to find nearest time include hours. The 3rd datetime should not be inside the dataframe. Instead, it is only inside the 2nd dataframe.

Comment: @roudan Are the datetimes sorted (ascending)? Why are you subtracting `timedelta(days=0.01)`? Please explain the logic about the searching a little bit more...

Comment: Thx Andrew yes the time index is ascending. I am using timedelta  just make time range a little bit wider to make sure date to find is within the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) approach :

```
def default_idx(df):
    return df.set_index(
        pd.Series(range(len(df))), append=True)

dfs = [df_tomatch_1, df_tomatch_2]

df = pd.concat(map(default_idx, dfs), keys=range(len(dfs)))
    
matches = (pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1))
               .get_indexer(time_tomatch, method="nearest"))
```

Output :

```
df.iloc[matches].index
# MultiIndex([(0, '2023-01-01 11:00', 1),
#             (0, '2023-01-01 13:00', 3),
#             (1, '2023-01-02 12:00', 2)],
#            )

df.iloc[matches].index.droplevel(1).tolist() # OP's expected output
# [(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: yes Timeless, it works much faster. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert to datetime only the first/last index (if you need to subtract the Timedelta) and use `bisect` module to find the right index:

```py
from bisect import bisect


def find_matched_date_index(df_tomatch_list, time_tomatch):
    d = pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
    time_tomatch_converted = [pd.to_datetime(t) for t in time_tomatch]
    for i, df in enumerate(df_tomatch_list):
        t1 = pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) - d
        t2 = pd.to_datetime(df.index[-1]) + d

        for j, t in enumerate(time_tomatch_converted):
            if t1 <= t <= t2:
                yield i, bisect(df.index, time_tomatch[j])


time_tomatch = ["2023-01-01 10:30", "2023-01-01 12:30", "2023-01-02 11:30"]

indx_time = list(find_matched_date_index([df_tomatch_1, df_tomatch_2], time_tomatch))
print(indx_time)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, I appreciate it. but you still are using 2 for loop, which will be slow too.

Comment: @roudan Did you measure it? There always be a loop (albeit hidden somewhere).